# Using runas to execute a minimized application

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch-file, cmd.exe

How can I run an application as another user and have that application's window minimized. Unfortunately, that application has no preference setting to have it start minimized.

```
runas /savecred /user:otheruser "!ProgramFiles(x86)!\path\to\application.exe"
```

I place that line inside a .cmd file and double click on it.

Comment: In a batch file you can use 'start "" 'path' /min ', which I assume can be combined with the runas command

Comment: Do you search for a built in solution like PowerShells `Start-Process` offers or an additional app just to use it in cmd?

Answer (score 0):

You can runas your application using your above code and try to insert `start /min myfile.bat` for minimizing your application.

[Source](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/RunAs.htm)

Comment: This minimizes the Command Prompt window that runs the batch file, but doesn't actually minimize the program (application.exe) started by the batch file.

Comment: Minimizing application should be present in the application code, as an example try this: `start /min "" "C:\Windows\notepad.exe"`. Here windows default application notepad has the minimizing feature. If the application doesn't have the minimizing code then it don't work.

Comment: Exactly what i stated in my last comment. In this case, the initial file that's being launched is the bat/cmd file, and the application is launched from within that batch/cmd file. So "start /min" isn't an option here. And combining Start/ min with runas doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yes, does the application which your are using has the minimized code?

Comment: Notepad.exe doesn't have the code. It's "start" that forces Notepad to open in minimized state. What I'm saying is start /min doesn't work with runas (which again is a host app) which launches another app.