# How to launch minimized application from RunAs?

Tags: cmd.exe, runas

I have a batch that runs in Windows 10 with elevated privileges so it's able to stop a few programs, backup/restore files, then relaunch those programs again.

The programs must be launched with normal privileges, otherwise some don't work properly. I googled for a solution and found one that works for most programs:

```
RunAs /savecred /user:myaccount "\"path to program\" /parameters"
```

I want 2 of those programs to start minimized (explorer.exe and excel.exe), previously I was using "start "" /min "path to program", but with RunAs, "start" isn't recognized as a program because it doesn't exist as a .exe, is there a way to run "start" from within RunAs, or any other way to launch programs in minimized state from RunAs?

As an example, if I run from an elevated cmd:

```
start /min "C:\Windows\notepad.exe" -> starts elevated + minimized
RunAs /savecred /user:myaccount "C:\Windows\notepad.exe" -> starts not-elevated
RunAs /savecred /user:myaccount "start /min C:\Windows\notepad.exe" -> cannot find specified file
RunAs /savecred /user:myaccount "\"start\" /min \"C:\Windows\notepad.exe\"" -> cannot find specified file
```

EDIT: similar to [this topic](https://superuser.com/questions/1059115/using-runas-to-execute-a-minimized-application) started 6 years ago, they also suggest using "start" with RunAs, but it simply doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. You could consider splitting the batch file in two (either two files or with a switch) where only the portion that has to be elevated actually runs elevated.

Comment: The elevated batch relaunches the programs mid batch, so it has to return to the batch. I tried using RunAs to "call" a second batch, but "call" isn't recognized either because it's also not an executable.

Comment: If you want `cmd` to do something, you can use `cmd /c "something"`. Where _something_ can be any built-in command. // My idea was more along to lines of strictly separating the steps (start regular, elevate to do stuff, continue in regular with re-launching applications).

Comment: `cmd` doesn't have any option to minimize programs, and it seems even `start /min` also isn't working with explorer. I did find an "ugly" workaround though: using an external tool called `cmdow.exe` I can use `for /f "tokens=1" %a in ('cmdow.exe /t ^| find /i "excel"') do cmdow.exe %a /min` to minimize the excel window after launch. The same applies to the explorer window.